# replace values in one dataset with values in another dataset R

Tags: r

I have a somewhat seemingly simple problem that I am stumped with. I have a df, say:

```
x y z
0 1 2
3 5 4
1 0 5
0 5 0
```

and another:

```
x y z
1 5 6
2 4 5
4 5 7
5 8 5
```

I want to replace the zero values in df1 with the value in df2. E.g., cell 1 of df1 would be 1 instead of zero. I want this for all columns in a dataframe. Can you help me code? I cant seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can locate the indices of  0's using `which`

```
zero_locations <- which(df1 == 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Then, you can use the locations to make the replacements:

```
df1[zero_locations] <- df2[zero_locations]
```

As David Arenburg pointed out in the comments, `which` isn't strictly necessary:

```
zero_locations <- df1 == 0
```

Will work as well.

Comment: not sure what you need `which` for, why not just  `zero_locations <- df1 == 0` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg you're right, it's not necessary.  I initially thought using `which` would be a more memory efficient solution than creating a logical matrix with the same dimensions as the original data frame, but that's only true and significant when the data frame is large and there are relatively few zeroes.